# can anyone tell me why this function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a simple function but it is not working and i don't understand why? i just want it to check to see if it is a number? And it's not over a 100. Am i not able to mix Jquery and java script?

```
$('.btnNumber').click(function () {
var val = $(this).prev(".number").val();
});


function (tty) (value){
if (! $.isNumeric(value)) {
    msg = 'Please enter a valid number';
}
else if (parseInt(value, 10) > 100) {
    msg = 'Enter number less than 100';        
}
else {
    msg = 'Thank you for the wonderful number: ' + value;
}
}
tty(val)
```

Comment: function (tty) (value) typo?

Comment: `function tty(value){`

Comment: Before posting a question you should verify if your syntax is valid first... This should help http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: Also, `var val = ...` is inside your `click` handler, so `tty(val)` doesn't have access to it.

Comment: *"Am i not able to mix Jquery and java script?"* It's impossible to use jQuery without using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the basic syntax error in where:

```
function (tty) (value){
```

Should be:

```
function tty(value) {
```

To make your fiddle work, some other changes were due:

```
$('.btnNumber').click(function () {
    var val = $(this).prev(".number").val();
    $('.feedback').text(tty(val));
});

function tty (value){
    if (! $.isNumeric(value)) {
        return 'Please enter a valid number';
    }
    else if (parseInt(value, 10) > 100) {
        return 'Enter number less than 100';        
    }
    else {
        return 'Thank you for the wonderful number: ' + value;
    }
}
```

It is much better to use the `return` statement instead of assigning values to global variables.

[**Check your fiddle here**, updated](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/sYk4E/2/).

Next time check the console. <kbd>F12</kbd> will open it in most browsers/plugins.

Comment: lol wow i missed that...but even with out that still don't work? http://jsfiddle.net/philyphil/sYk4E/1/

Comment: @philly do you check you console sometimes? And read comment, here one of Crazy Train who made a nice comment as usual

Comment: @philly I edited your fiddle. Check the updated answer.

Comment: @acdcjunior i see the same one no updates.

Comment: This link: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/sYk4E/2/

Comment: @roasted no i don't what do you mean by console? i don't use f12 ever

Comment: @acdcjunior i see thank you very much, what is the difference with yours and mine? i see you have  $('.feedback').text(tty(val)); in the click

Comment: @philly `$('.feedback').text("myStringHere");` updates the text of `<div class="feedback"></div>` (actually, any element with the `feedback` class). Without calling `$('.feedback').text(tty(val));`, you were just calculating the message (`tty(val)`) and doing nothing with it. I figured you wanted to update the `div`'s text and did that.

Comment: @philly ya console is F12, you should always use it

Comment: @philly about the console, what browser do you use? I have Chrome and IE 10 here. Both open the console when I hit F12. With firefox, I installed the Firebug extension. **F12** opens its console as well. (I hear newest firefoxes do not require installing that extension to open a similar console.)

Comment: @acdcjunior i'm new to this what do you use the console for? i have firefox.

Comment: Console it's where the browser shows all error messages (such as syntax errors). As you have firefox, you should get the Firebug extension: http://getfirebug.com/ . Go to this site, install the extension and then (after a firefox restar, probably) press **F12**: The console will open. This is an image of the console open: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/_images/firebug_logging.png

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks i will start using it every time! I am used to using console log's in editors from class so i have been kind of lost without it. this is kind of the same thing.

Comment: @acdcjunior wow this is really cool i have it up on this page and it is showing how everything is set up.

Comment: @philly Yeah. I can't live without it anymore. Shows everything. Even network requests/responses to/from the web server. Really useful!

Answer (score 1):

```
function (tty) (value){
```

That is not a valid syntax

you should write

```
function  tty( value){
```

And  the variable `val` scope wont work out side of the click function.If you want so,Please assign it to a global variable and use it.

Comment: here it is function tty(value){...} i think

Comment: @Crazy Train when i click submit i thought var val would have a value, and i can put it into my function?

Comment: You cannot philly.It is outside of the scope.Make a global variable and use it.